# Селекты в форме

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть форма, в ней селект, нужно сделать следующее: при выборе в селекте какого-то пункта, например "автонамотка", должно появиться всплывающее окошко для выбора типа намотки. с таким вопросом еще не сталкивался, за меня все делать не прошу а хотябы подтолкните от чего исходить в этом вопросе. Спасибо!

```
<form method='post'>
    <div>
         <select name=''>
              <option value=''>--Выберите--</option>
              <option value=''>Ручная</option>
              <option value=''>Автонамотка</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div>
         <p><input type="radio"> Тип 1</p>
         <p><input type="radio"> Тип 2</p>
         <p><input type="radio"> Тип 3</p>
         <p><input type="radio"> Тип 4</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скрыть блок с типами, при выборе в селекте смотреть значение, если нужное - показывать.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
#radios
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_avt()
{
    if (document.getElementById('myselect').value=='2')
    {
    document.getElementById('radios').style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('radios').style.display='none';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post'> 
<div> 
<select name='' id='myselect' onChange='show_avt()'> 
<option value=''>--Выберите--</option> 
<option value='1'>Ручная</option>
<option value='2'>Автонамотка</option> 
</select>
</div> 
<div id='radios'>
<input type="radio"> Тип 1<br/>
<input type="radio"> Тип 2<br/>
<input type="radio"> Тип 3<br/>
<input type="radio"> Тип 4
</div> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо за ясность, помогли!